# Protect against POST //cgi-bin/php attacks?

Tags: php, apache

I am being attacked with this cgi injection:

> POST
>   //%63%67%69%2D%62%69%6E/%70%68%70?%2D%64+%61%6C%6C%6F%77%5F%75%72%6C%5F%69%6E%63%6C%75%64%65%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%73%61%66%65%5F%6D%6F%64%65%3D%6F%66%66+%2D%64+%73%75%68%6F%73%69%6E%2E%73%69%6D%75%6C%61%74%69%6F%6E%3D%6F%6E+%2D%64+%64%69%73%61%62%6C%65%5F%66%75%6E%63%74%69%6F%6E%73%3D%22%22+%2D%64+%6F%70%65%6E%5F%62%61%73%65%64%69%72%3D%6E%6F%6E%65+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%66%6F%72%63%65%5F%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%3D%30+%2D%64+%63%67%69%2E%72%65%64%69%72%65%63%74%5F%73%74%61%74%75%73%5F%65%6E%76%3D%30+%2D%64+%61%75%74%6F%5F%70%72%65%70%65%6E%64%5F%66%69%6C%65%3D%70%68%70%3A%2F%2F%69%6E%70%75%74+%2D%6E
>   HTTP/1.1

This decodes as

> //cgi-bin/php?-d allow_url_include=on -d safe_mode=off -d
>   suhosin.simulation=on -d disable_functions="" -d open_basedir=none -d
>   auto_prepend_file=php://input -d cgi.force_redirect=0 -d
>   cgi.redirect_status_env=0 -d auto_prepend_file=php://input -n

Php version is 5.2.6-1+lenny13, yes thats old.

How can I prevent this attack?

Comment: Update your PHP to the latest version. You are missing out a lot.

Comment: @Ebenezar `apt-get upgrade php` has nothing to do. System upgrade is not possible at the moment.

Comment: Upgrade to at *least* Squeeze. Lenny is EOL and has been for a while.

Comment: @Shadur Yes, sure this will be done at the next possible date. I needed a quick fix until then.

Comment: This is not the only critical vulnerability that affects your system.  You need to upgrade,  that is the only option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A **system upgrade is required** but here a quick fix.

In `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` I comment out:

> ```
>    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
>    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
>            AllowOverride None
>            Options ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
>            Order allow,deny
>            Allow from all
>    </Directory>
> ```

And did a `apache2ctl restart`. Now `/cgi-bin/php` is not accessible anymore. That should fix it.

Wonder why this is in default anyway. You should also check other pages in `sites-enabled`. Do a `grep "ExecCGI" /etc/apache2/sites-enabled`.

Comment: It works very well!

Answer (score 5):

Besides the obvious *update everything* advice, the simplest solution is **don't put your php interpreter in your cgi-bin directory**. In fact, don't put *any* interpreter in your cgi-bin directory; not php, not perl, not bash, not sed, not awk, not vi, nor *any* program that executes arbitrary commands passed to it.

If your hosting configuration requires that your interpreter be put in cgi-bin, then change your hosting configuration. There are plenty of reasonable alternatives that don't resort to this silly idea.

Comment: Does nginx also have a concept of cgi-bin and can it be susceptible to this attack?